# C# Adding items to listview gets bugged by threads?

Tags: c#, listview

So I have an piece of code which adds information to listView, but it seems like it gets someway of "bugged". So, I have 2 pieces of information. It adds one perfectly, but if it adds the 2nd one it tells me that, it already exists there & shows me first item name, so basically somehow it tries to add same thing 2 times.

```
info.Text = Username;
info.SubItems.Add(Password);
info.SubItems.Add(Points.ToString());
info.SubItems.Add(Level.ToString());
listView1.Items.Add(info);
```

I tried also "debugging" it, by seeing console input for Username, Password etc.. All of those were different.

//EDIT

I just did 2nd debug, if information gets passed to addItems() void, then data changes, so I think it gets somehow bugged by threads.

Comment: Sorry, are you doing a `new ListViewItem();` each time?

Comment: Not each time, I called it on start of a program.

Comment: So you can't actually add it again... if I correctly understand what is going on... Please share more of your code and what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Basically, there's void loginToServer & addItem. It gets info from loginToServer & shows to console all info, both are different username etc, but after it's sent to addItem void & from there I do console.write username.... etc then both info is same. Like example: at first info is Peter & James, if it's in addItems void and I get it from there by console then both are Peter & Peter.

Comment: Sorry, but it's better if you add the full code in your question and you explain it there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Apologies if this was not the solution you were looking for. With some lack in details on your question this was made from what I could possibly understand**

Is info a custom class? If so I would assume SubItems is a List object as well. If these scenarios are correct then your class should look something like

```
public class info
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<string> SubItems { get; set; }

    /* Other Code */
}
```

Now if I am not mistaken it seems like you are trying to serialize the data into a string and then add to the ListView? If so there are a few ways you could go about doing this:

```
public class info
{
    /* Other Code */

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Username: {Text}; Password: {SubItems[0]}; Points: {SubItems[1]}; Level: {SubItems[2]};"
    }
}
```

Now in case all of this is true you could now perform:

```
info PersonInfo = new Info()
{
    Text = Username;
    SubItems = new List<string>()
    {
        Password,
        Points.ToString();
        Level.ToString();
    }
}

ListView1.Items.Add(ParsonInfo.ToString());
```

Comment: Hmm, basically. After receiving information from servers, it will pass the info to addItem void, but seems like because of threading the info changes to the first one. So if one is Peter, 2nd is James and info gets passed, then info inside the addItem void is Peter & Peter.

Comment: To get info I am using Invoke, because it's required, but I am not using invoke in adding the items, because seems like there it's not required.

Comment: Are you by chance creating new instances of the info class? Keep in mind if you have objects set to static then "only one" could exist. So by possibly creating a new info instance:
info Peter = new Info()
info James = new Info()
then do
ListView1.Items.Add(Peter);
ListView1.Items.Add(James);
Of course in a much more robust way!